# How can I format a javascript date to be serialized by jQuery

Tags: c#, json, serialization, date, castle-monorail

I am trying to set a `javascript` `date` so that it can be submitted via `JSON` to a `.NET` type, but when attempting to do this, `jQuery` sets the `date` to a full `string`, what format does it have to be in to be converted to a `.NET` type?

```
var regDate = student.RegistrationDate.getMonth() + "/" + student.RegistrationDate.getDate() + "/" + student.RegistrationDate.getFullYear();
j("#student_registrationdate").val(regDate); // value to serialize
```

I am using `MonoRail` on the server to perform the binding to a `.NET` type, that aside I need to know what to set the form hidden field value to, to get properly sent to `.NET` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8.aspx) has some example Date strings that are parse-able is that what you're looking for?

```
string dateString = "5/1/2008 8:30:52 AM";
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(dateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

As travis suggests, you could simply change the parameter or class property (depending on what you are passing back) to a string, the parse it as his example.

You may also want to take a look at [this article](http://www.nikhilk.net/DateSyntaxForJSON2.aspx).  It suggests that direct conversion for DateTime JSON serialization uses something more like the ticks property.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the YYYY-MM-DD notation which offer the best combo of unambiguity and readability.

so:

`var regDate = student.RegistrationDate.getFullYear() + "-" + student.RegistrationDate.getMonth() + "-" + student.RegistrationDate.getDate();
j("#student_registrationdate").val(regDate);`